# How to change gVim width when open/close vimfiler or tagbar?

Tags: plugin-tagbar

I'm just new to vim script, and I want to make gVim width auto adjust when open/close vimfiler or tagbar window.

Here's my *not working* Vim script:

```
let g:window_raw_width = 90
let g:window_width = g:window_raw_width

function adjust_tagbar_width()
    if (g:window_width == g:window_raw_width)
        g:window_width = g:window_raw_width + 40
        
    else
        g:window_width = g:window_raw_width
    endif
    set lines=g:window_width
endfunction

nmap <F9> :TagbarToggle<cr>
autocmd VimEnter,BufNewFile,BufRead * nested :TagbarToggle<cr>
```

Comment: set lines=<number> changes window height. If i clearly understand your question, you need to change column.
set columns=g:window_width

Comment: @AlexKroll , I think I did set lines=g:window_width, how to auto call this function when I open gvim ?

Comment: You might need to put string 'call adjust_tagbar_width()' into ~/.vimrc 
And map key to chained call
nmap <F9> :TagbarToggle<cr>:call adjust_tagbar_width()<cr>

Answer (score 2):

Function name should start from capital letter

```
let g:is_tagbar=0

function Adjust_tagbar_width()

    if (g:is_tagbar==0)
      let g:is_tagbar=1
      set columns=120
    else
      let g:is_tagbar=0
      set columns=80
    endif
endfunction

nmap <F9> :TagbarToggle<CR> :exec Adjust_tagbar_width() <CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

finally, I found the answer after some years. add below in *.vimrc*

```
let g:tagbar_width = winwidth(0) * 10/100
```

it set the *taglist* 10 percent of screen.